# Insert a row in child table based on a condition from parent table - Oracle DBMS

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a table structure like

```
 create table EMPLOYE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    NAS varchar2(100),
    CONSTRAINT employe_pk primary key (CodeEmploye)
);

create table SALAIRE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    Mois number not null,
    CONSTRAINT salaire_pk primary key (CodeEmploye, Mois),
    CONSTRAINT salaire_code_employe_fk FOREIGN KEY(CodeEmploye) REFERENCES EMPLOYE(CodeEmploye)
);
```

I want to add a constraint where I should not be allowed to insert a row in SALAIRE table if the corresponding CodeEmploye in the EMPLOYE table NAS = NULL

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this uses computed columns:

```
create table EMPLOYE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    NAS varchar2(100),
    CONSTRAINT employe_pk primary key (CodeEmploye),
    has_nas generated always as (case when nas is null then 0 else 1 end),
    CONSTRAINT unq_codeemploye_has_nas UNIQUE (CodeEmploye, has_nas)
);

create table SALAIRE (
    CodeEmploye varchar2(100) not null,
    Mois number not null,
    has_nas generated always as (1),
    CONSTRAINT salaire_pk primary key (CodeEmploye, Mois),
    CONSTRAINT salaire_code_employe_fk FOREIGN KEY(CodeEmploye, has_nas) REFERENCES EMPLOYE(CodeEmploye, has_nas)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ee3eefdb5fb39f4c7d78e8ba099509e) is a db<>fiddle.